# ASP.NET Core MVC - Model Binding does not work for POST Request when Number Properties are Declared as Strings Client-Side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller route in ASP.NET Core that accepts application/json data. I was intending to convert some form data on the client-side into JSON as follows:

```
let formElement = document.getElementById("form-data");
let formData = new FormData(formElement);
let formJson = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

console.log("submitting:", formJson)

let response = await request("/mycontroller/addnew", "POST", formJson);
```

With the server-side route as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddNew([FromBody] MyFormData formData )
{
    // Do Stuff
}

public class MyFormData 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

With the example setup above, I can get the `MyFormData` model to bind correctly if I submit:

```json
{
    "id": 123,
    "message": "testing testing"
}
```

However, when I submit the following, formData is null:

```json
{
    "id": "123",
    "message": "testing testing"
}
```

Given that you cannot specify data types in the HTML form, it'd be a pain to explicitly cast all my properties to their correct types. The documentation below also implies that the server should be able to handle numbers expressed as strings by default:

https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Am I missing anything obvious here or is this expected behaviour?

Comment: With what content-type are you posting this data?

Comment: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: try application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: The model on client and server have to use same type.  Also server for request should be HttpGet (not HttpPost).  See example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2?force_isolation=true.  What should happen is following 1) Client sends request using HttpPost 2) Server receives request using HttpGet 3) Server processes request 4) Server sends response with HttpPost 5) Client receives response using HttpGet.

Comment: @Devilscomrade It can be successful if you post `formData` object with `[FromForm]` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from .NET Core 5, it looks as though you can configure number handling as follows:

```cs
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString );
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.numberhandling?view=net-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-numberhandling

For older versions, the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` approach is probably the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the modelbinding is not behaving as you expect it.
This can be configured in the startup with:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null; });
```

Also, I have solved this issue in my projects with using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as content-type in the post requests in the clientside. You may need to remove the [frombody] tag if you're using this method.